# Develop more efficient for loop that refers to n-1 row

Tags: r

I need to run a logic where the "n" step is based on the result of the "n-1" step, and thus i implemented the logic in a for loop. Here the code:

```
library(data.table)
df<-as.data.table(matrix(rexp(100000, rate=.1), ncol=1000))
weight<-as.data.table(matrix(rexp(100, rate=10), ncol=1))

for (row in 1:nrow(weight))
{
  if (row > 2){

    # from second row start the logic
    # We create weighted averages of variables values: value(n-1)* (1-weight) + value(n) * weight
    df[row] <- 
      df[row-1,] * as.numeric(1 - weight[row]) + df[row,] * as.numeric(weight[row])

  }
}
```

However, it takes really long time to run because the data.table, in reality, is made of 1098 columns and 200k rows.

Does anybody have a ideas on how to develop a more efficient solution?

Comment: I think you can try going to pencil & paper, at a glance I think there's a closed-form solution that doesn't require recursion

Comment: @ MichaelChirco I tried but i can´t find a solution because it´s referencing to the previous step

Comment: `x[i] = r * x[i-1]` is also like that, but the `n`th step will be `r^(n-1) * x[0]` right? so even recursive problems can have non-recursive solutions

Comment: @MichaelChirico, as each step includes the data and some weights (random values) I don't see a possible solution that does not involve this "recursion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain my story how I would go about increasing the performance of such a task.

### Base Timings

First I recreate your data (a bit smaller) and measure the time it takes to run it:

```r
library(data.table)
library(tictoc) # for timing only

# easier way to create a data.table
NROWS <- 100
NCOLS <- 100
set.seed(123)

df_orig <- data.table(matrix(rexp(NROWS * NCOLS, rate = 0.1), ncol = NCOLS))
wt <- data.table(V1 = rexp(NROWS, rate = 10))


df1 <- copy(df_orig)
tic()
for (r in 1:nrow(wt)) {
  if (r >= 2) { # assuming you mean >= 2 not >= 3 (:= >2)
    # from second row start the logic
    # We create weighted averages of variables values: value(n-1)* (1-weight) + value(n) * weight
    df1[r, ] <- df1[r-1,] * as.numeric(1 - wt[r]) + df1[r,] * as.numeric(wt[r])
  }
}
toc()
#> 1.274 sec elapsed
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Model 2

Then I look at ways to improve the code. For example, `as.numeric()` might be expensive, as well as the `if ()` check in the loop. Lets remove that, but make sure that the results stay the same

```r
# no if check in the loop and replace as.numeric with [[1]]
# loop only from 2
df2 <- copy(df_orig)
tic()
for (r in 2:nrow(wt)) {
  df2[r, ] <- df2[r - 1, ] * (1 - wt[r][[1]]) + df2[r, ] * wt[r][[1]]
}
toc()
#> 1.149 sec elapsed

# check that the results are identical
all.equal(df1, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A little bit better, but we are not there yet.

### Matrix Model

In general `data.table` is a great way to improve speeds, but this kind of access is best implemented in a base structure, i.e., `matrix()`.

So lets do that:

```r
# Matrix based
mdf <- as.matrix(df_orig)
mwt <- as.matrix(wt)

tic()
for (r in 2:nrow(wt)) {
  mdf[r, ] <- mdf[r - 1, ] * (1 - mwt[r, ]) + mdf[r, ] * mwt[r, 1]
}
toc()
#> 0.005 sec elapsed

df3 <- data.table(mdf)

all.equal(df3, df1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

That looks like a nice speedup!

But there is more...

### `Rcpp` Model

Especially in these kinds of tasks, `Rcpp` and `c++` are more cumbersome to write, but provide beautiful speedups.
Here we use the [`Armadillo`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) matrix library for `c++` and its `Rcpp` bindings of [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html).

Translating your code to `Rcpp` yields this:

```r
# using rcpp
rcpp_code <- "// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat my_rcpp_fun(arma::mat data, arma::mat weights) {
  const int len = weights.size();

  // Cpp starts indexing at 0, so 1 is the second row!
  for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    data.row(i) = data.row(i - 1) * (1 - weights.row(i)(0)) + data.row(i) * weights.row(i)(0);
  }
  return data;
}
"

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = rcpp_code)
mdf2 <- as.matrix(df_orig)
mwt2 <- as.matrix(wt)

tic()
mdf4 <- my_rcpp_fun(mdf2, mwt2)
toc()
#> 0.002 sec elapsed

df4 <- data.table(mdf4)
all.equal(df4, df1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

From 1.274s to 0.002s sounds nice right?!

Comment: c++ can be a bit intimidating, if you have questions, feel free to ask them below. If this answers your question, please consider marking it as solved (green arrow)!

Comment: amazing! Would have never expected such improvement!